# Where does the split happen between Mai-Hime and Mai-Otome?

Tags: mai-hime, mai-otome

I know that Mai-Hime and Mai-Otome are anime (and maybe manga) series that are related by have different plots. I was wondering if there is a certain point where they split (like FMA and FMA: Brotherhood) or if they are entirely different plot-wise. If they are different, how are they connected beyond being created by the same production company?

Comment: well does it still have the same point to the story that there is a girl that wants to protect everyone and everything important to her in her life. does she have parents? does she have a brother? does she have someone she likes? does she have friends that try to kill her? does she save them all in the end? does she die and come back to life? is she forest to marry someone she does not even like? is she given magic powers that she does not know how to use and fights monsters? that is all for know bye and thx

Answer (score 3):

They're entirely different story wise, My-HiME is set more or less in our world while My-Z HiME (My Otome) is set in a fictional universe.

They are roughly connected by the character and their personalities that exists in both series, such as Mai's and Natsuki's rivalry, Natsuki's Same Sex Relationship with Shizuru (In My-Z HiME they are much more open, in My-HiME they only are open with each other about their feeling near the end) and Haruka hot tempered personality and malapropism with Yukino always correcting her.

Also both series portray the females being the ones with power having to also come to terms with their adolescence and love at the same time as controling this power. in My-HiME it was choosing to have power at the cost of the person the girl loved the most (the warning Natsuki gives Mai before she awakens her Child) while with My-Z HiME it was choosing to have power and never being with a male (explained by how the Y Chromosome will destroy the Nano Machines and thus Otome's can't have any relationship with men)

Comment: Actually, it was Nagi who warned Mai, not Natsuki. An ambiguous and rather useless warning that she'd be putting her "most precious" or "most important" thing on the line - the implication being her life, when in reality it's the person most important to her.

Answer (score 1):

The *Mai-HiME* series is the principal anime where Hime, an ancient power that is born inside chosen people that will fight to determine the master of the new millennium (between good vs evil) and a foreign organization trying to sway the results by mimicking that power.

The *Mai-Otome* series is supposed to be set a millennium later after human have migrated to another planet. The technology that was used by humans to be able to finally reach the stars is the exact tech develop after trying to mimic the Hime ability. And as to a millennium have passed... the Hime users was reborn a new, and the darkness follows behind them in a different form.....